# Lua logitech mouse 180/360 degree turn

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech-gaming-software

As the title says I'm trying to figure out how to get this piece of stolen code to work :p

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(5) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  end
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3) then
    recoil = not recoil
    spot = not spot
  end

  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and recoil) then
    if recoil then
      repeat
        Sleep(1)
        MoveMouseRelative(-400, 0)
        Sleep(1)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
    end
  end
end
```

No matter what sleep timer I add I can't get it to work the way I want : I want a single press pixel perfect 180/360 degree turn in call of duty and not have to hold down the mb5 button in order to turn.

Comment: You better not steal code or even worse, publish stolen code.

Comment: @Twonky - github exists for a single purpose: for stealing code.  And for publishing code which is ready to be stolen ;-)

Comment: @Egor taking what was intended to be taken is not stealing. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  
MoveAmount = -400
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(4) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  end
  
  

  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
    for x=1,10,1
    do
        MoveMouseRelative(MoveAmount, 0)
        Sleep(5)
       
    end
      
      
    
  end
end
```

Comment: This works on desktop ... setting value to high seems to crash it so just moved a small amount multiple time. Will move once per mouse click so if you hold key down it wont repeat.

Answer (score 0):

While you're holding down mb5, then every 2 seconds, this line of code is happening:

`MoveMouseRelative(-400, 0)`

I guess the problem is that moving the mouse -400 pixels isn't exactly a 180 degree turn, and the correct number will probably be different for everyone depending on their mouse sensitivity settings.

You could try some different numbers instead of -400 to see if it works more like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
   if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   end
   if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3) then
      recoil = not recoil
      spot = not spot
   end
   if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and recoil) then
      local distance = 400  -- adjust this value
      while distance > 0 do
         local delta = math.min(100, distance)
         distance = distance - delta
         MoveMouseRelative(-delta, 0)
         Sleep(15)
      end
   end
end
```